# Did the Douglas SBD Dauntless have a second set of controls?

Tags: aircraft-design, military, flight-controls, aviation-history

In the book *Never Call me a Hero*, the author mentions that there were controls in the rear seat of the [Douglas SBD Dauntless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_SBD_Dauntless). However, I don't recall ever hearing this before, though I know the TBD had controls in the second seat. Did the SBD have controls in the rear seat?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Dauntless did have controls for the rear gunner- a pair of permanently attached rudder pedals and a control stick that was stowed away on the port side until needed. See:

https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/warships1discussionboards/sbd-dauntless-flyable-from-rear-cockpit-t2435.html

Juan Jimenez is correct that it would be very difficult to operate, what with the armour plate for the pilot and the radios right in front of the gunner. See here for a story of flying a veteran Dauntless where the pilot gets a brief familiarisation flight from the gunner's seat (it's mentioned in the fourth paragraph after "SBD Glider: Engine Out"):

https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2011/january/pilot/flying-a-national-treasure-the-sbd-dauntless

You can see the gunner's control view at the Smithsonian's walk-around view of the Dauntless, it's images four and seven in the collection (six shows the pilot's view and eight the gunner's *real* place of business):

https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/douglas-sbd-6-dauntless

Photo seven
[image]

Comment: I stand corrected, and I would hate to be the poor soul stuck with trying to land that on a carrier with a disabled or dead pilot up front.

Comment: Agreed, I think the limit to flying from the rear seat would be "roughly straight and vaguely level" for as long as it takes the pilot to finish scribbling on his maps or until the plane was in a safe-ish place for a bail-out.

Comment: No kidding. There is no panel back there! No instruments, no navigation, nothing. i wonder if the gunner could even use the radio! That's nuts.

Comment: Also: Very nice for a first answer! Welcome!

Comment: @JuanJimenez Even without a radio, a few warning shots above the tower should be sufficient for landing clearance.

Comment: https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/20951/how-does-a-blind-passenger-not-die-if-driver-becomes-unconscious

Comment: Interestingly, I came across a story of actual use of the rear gunner flying the aircraft because the pilot was wounded / disoriented, during the Guadalcanal campaign. It was even during a night flight.  It's in the book The Battle for Hell's Island.

Answer (score 4):

The concept of the rear controls (stick and rudder pedals) was two fold in that

1. the gunner/radio operator could recover the aircraft in a nose up climb attitude if/when the pilot blacked out from excessive G  during a dive

and

2. the aircraft could be recovered to straight and level should the pilot be incapacitated allowing the rear seater to bail out. The rear controls were never intended to land this aircraft. Interestingly the Germans incorporated an auto recovery capability into their Stukas in the early 1930s, this technology was never adopted by US manufacturers

Comment: Wouldn't the gunner black out from excessive G before the pilot? The pilot is causing it, therefore he's anticipating it and that should slightly increase his resistance to it even if back then they didn't know the right tricks for it.

Answer (score 0):

The gunner always controlled the radio but he had no access to tail hook, engine control beyond throttle or anything else much needed to land safely on a ship.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).